# Equivalent of Stata joinby() on R?

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to code a Stata code on R and I can't seem to find the equivalent of `joinby()` on R.
`joinby()` combines 2 datasets horizontally but form all pairwise combinations
within group.

I have two dataframes: one of 100 Hospitals and the other one of 10,000 GPs. I'd need to match all the GPs to each hospital - I'd end up having 100*10,000=1,000,000 rows in my resulting dataframe after combination.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `?expand.grid` or `data.table::CJ`

Answer (score 2):

There may be a more concise method, but the following should work, say your hospital data.frame, hospDf, is unique by hospital as is you doctor docDf. You can use `expand.grid` to get a data.frame of all hospital-doctor combinations:

```
hospDocDf <- expand.grid(hospDf$hospID, docDf$docID)
```

Then merge both data.frames onto this one:

```
hospDocDf <- merge(hospDocDf, hospDf, by="hospID", all.x=TRUE)
hospDocDf <- merge(hospDocDf, DocDf, by="docID", all.x=TRUE)
```

The all.x=TRUE argument is not necessary, but it doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cross join merge which is essentially a merge with no `by` argument. This will return the cartesian product between both sets 100 X 10,000:

```
df <- merge(hospitaldata, gpsdata)
```

Comment: curious answer, but very slow compared to `expand.grid`

Comment: Works for my needs! OP can define a key of same value `hospitaldata$key <- 1` in both datasets and use the key in `by` argument.